# Cakephp 2 dependent select box not populating option values

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I need to populate a bank documents select box after choosing one bank from the previous select box .

I try the code from this excelent tutorial :[Dynamic select box with CakePHP 2.0](http://www.willis-owen.co.uk/2011/11/dynamic-select-box-with-cakephp-2-0/)

When debugging i can see on the network tab that i have the right values for the select option documents from the choosen bank.

The problem is that the values are not updating the select box in the browser , just remains the first old values, while i see at the network tab they are there .

How can i fix ?

My code is  :

The select box where i choose the bank :

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Payment.bank_code', array(
        'label' => 'Bank',
    ));
?>
```

The select box wich need to be updated:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Payment.bank_type_documents', array(
        'label' => 'Type Doc',
    ));
?>
```

At the final section of the form i declare this code:

```
<?php

    $this->Js->get('#PaymentBankCode')->event('change', 
                $this->Js->request( array(
                            'controller'=>'paymentbanktypedocuments',
                            'action'=>'getBankTypeDocuments'
                        ), array(
                            'update'=>'#PaymentBankTypeDocuments',
                            'async' => true,
                            'method' => 'post',
                            'dataExpression'=>true,
                            'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
                            'isForm' => true,
                            'inline' => true
                        ))
                    )
                )
    );
?>
```

Controller method

```
 <?
       public function getBankTypeDocuments() {                
            $bank_id = $this->request->data['Payment']['bank_id'];        
            $this->loadModel('PaymentTypeDocuments');        
            $banktypedocuments = $this->PaymentTypeDocuments->find('list', array(
                'conditions' => array('PaymentTypeDocuments.bank_id' => $bank_id),
                'fields' => array('value','name'),
                'recursive' => -1
            ));        
            $this->set( 'banktypedocuments', $banktypedocuments );
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
        }
    ?>

//view
<?php foreach ($banktypedocuments as $key => $value): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Are you add Js writeBuffer to default.ctp?

Comment: Check javascript error in console and make sure that there is no any select box plugin not configured with your select box.

Comment: Yes i add Js writeBuffer at the end of default.ctp file

Comment: Yes! is there selectize select box plugin and a style=display:none inline css declaration how can i overrride this ?